# AngularJS console.log problems

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a small app with AngularJS to record heard rate values. But I get into troubles like:

the below is drawing a chart with low/high values of a heartRate monitor.
Everything works fine but the console gives me errors like

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M{{heartRate.date}} {{heartRate.high}} L {{heartRate.date}} {{heartRate.low}}"
```

and

```
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="{{heartRate.date}}"
```

I can't figure out what is wrong.
Here is the code for the html of the partial.
I leave out all other code as it is essentially trivial

many thanks
Peter

```
<svg style="width:900px; height:300px;">
                            <rect x="50" y="1" width="850" height="250px"     style="fill:transparent; stroke:grey; stroke-width=1px;"/>
                            <g class="xAxis">
                                <text x="50" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">Jan/2014</text>
                                <text x="150" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">Feb/2014</text>
                                <text x="250" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">Mar/2014</text>
                                <text x="350" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">Apr/2014</text>
                                <text x="450" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">May/2014</text>
                                <text x="550" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">Jun/2014</text>
                                <text x="650" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">Jul/2014</text>
                                <text x="750" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">Aug/2014</text>
                                <text x="850" y="270" style="text-anchor:middle;">Sep/2014</text>

                            </g>
                            <g class="yAxis">
                                <text x="40" y="250" style="text-anchor:end; baseline-shift:-0.5ex">50</text>
                                <text x="40" y="210" style="text-anchor:end; baseline-shift:-0.5ex">70</text>
                                <text x="40" y="170" style="text-anchor:end; baseline-shift:-0.5ex">90</text>
                                <text x="40" y="130" style="text-anchor:end; baseline-shift:-0.5ex">110</text>
                                <text x="40" y="90" style="text-anchor:end; baseline-shift:-0.5ex">130</text>
                                <text x="40" y="50" style="text-anchor:end; baseline-shift:-0.5ex">150</text>
                                 <text x="40" y="10" style="text-anchor:end; baseline-shift:-0.5ex">170</text>
                            </g>
                            <g ng-repeat="heartRate in heartRateValues">
                                <path d="M{{heartRate.date}} {{heartRate.high}} L {{heartRate.date}} {{heartRate.low}}" class="svgLine"/>
                                <circle cx="{{heartRate.date}}" cy="{{heartRate.high}}" r="3" class="svgCircle"/>
                                <circle cx="{{heartRate.date}}" cy="{{heartRate.low}}" r="3" class="svgCircle"/>
                            </g>

                        </svg>
```

Comment: That's not html, that svg. My guess when the browser is trying to interpret it, the values aren't interpolated yet, and so that causes the error (and not anything from angular).

Comment: Maybe you can try using custom comment directives to replace path and circle in the last `<g>` of the `<svg>` section.

Comment: on the circle elements, I succeeded with the use of ng-attr. Hence cx becomes ng-attr-cx="{{value}}". On the path, I am trying with your comment directive. Thx